# Which callback method called when coming back to a fragment from another added fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment [A], and I add a new fragment [B] through this code:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .addToBackStack(null).**add**(R.id.activity_content, fragment).commit();
```

I want to run some code when I come back to [A] from [B] using a back button. However, When clicking back button on fragment [B], none of the callback methods on [A] are called.

Given that I am adding a fragment through "add" and not "replace," are there any callback methods I can override in [A]?

Answer (score 0):

For this case you should probably add an `OnBackstackChangedListener`:

```
// Add this after the transaction...
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        // Do your logic here. Probably want to remove the
        // listener at this point too.
    }
});
```